# MYSQL ¿Como puedo manejar productos y servicios con 1 tabla pero que tengo que guardar informacion referente por separado?

Tags: base-de-datos, mysql-workbench

Muy buenas tardes, tengo un dilema y me gustaría saber su opinión.

Tengo que crear una tabla para guardar productos y servicios, pero cada 1 de estos cuenta con información ligada independiente.
Ejemplo:

Productos:
Se almacena en otra tabla los detalles de este, por ejemplo, sku, costo, precio, nombre, etc.

Servicios:
Se almacenan diferentes factores para saber si aplica 1 servicio a 1 producto, por ejemplo, el rango de peso, rango de tamaño; en base a esto se consulta en la BD's para saber qué servicio le aplicaría a el producto seleccionado.

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Saludos

Comment: Podrías dar más detalles sobre las tablas? los scripts de creación de las tablas y los detalles de lo que quieres obtener sería lo ideal

Comment: Parece que productos y servicios no pueden estar en una sola table, sino en dos, una para productos y otra para servicios, esta un poco confuso tu problema